# home network: Cat 7 S/FTP patch cable is too slow

Tags: cabling

I pulled some CAT 7 S/FTP cables inside my walls but when using those I only get around 70/400mbps. I should be getting 700/700 at least, which I do get connecting myself directly to the router.

I have tested different cables (cat5, cat6, cat7) between the wall cable and the computer and router.

I have tested pulling grounding cable and attached them to the wall cable where they connect to the cables connecting to router and computer.

If I do make a male patch cable out of the same cable that I have in the walls I do get speeds such as 700/700 when connecting directly to the router.

Could it be the female contacts of the wall cables? Do I need a special type of female contact for this CAT 7 S/FTP cable? On the package it said they should be good for CAT 7.

I have tested all cables with a network cable testing device to see that all wires are correctly connected and they are.

The wall cables are max around 5 meters in length.

Any clue why I only get around 70/400mbps when I do have a 1gbps line?

[image: grounding]
[image: wall to router]
[image: wall to computer]

Comment: What is that connector on the cable from the wall? And indeed what kind of cable is coming from the wall? It looks like Coax ...

Comment: They are Cat6A FTP and Cat6A STP connectors. I have tried Cat6A FTP and Cat6A STP on one wall cable or Cat6A STP and Cat6A STP on one wall cable. RJ45 on both. The cable from the wall is Cat7 S/FTP.

Comment: How did you conclude that the cable is the problem and not the router ?

Comment: When I skip the wall cable and connect directly to the router I do get high speeds.

Comment: And as you can see on the picture I have 4 wall cables with connectors attached, all 4 has been tested with the same results. This is why I suspect the connectors on the wall cables to be the problem. I put the correct colors to the correct numbers (same on both sides). I pulled the grounding strand inside the connectors who had support for them and twirled it around the end of the foil/net on the ones who did not. I made sure that the hole where the wall cable is entering touches the net and foil. I might not have the correct terminology but I hope you understand what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

After a bunch of random testing with cables and router ports I notice an inconsistency in speeds. The problem was solved just by updating my router settings.

Comment: "just update the settings" is probably the most vague description of a solution, ever

Comment: I could have said "updating the firmware", that's as much as I can tell you. I'm not sure what the firmware changed. You'll have to do with vague because that's as much as I know and will research about it.